# Prove that the sets are open

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

How can I prove that the following sets are open?

1. {$(x, y) \in R^{2}$: $y > x^{2}$}
2. {$(x, y) \in R^{2}$: $x^2 + y^2 > 1$}

My proof has to use this definition:
A set $S ⊆ R^{n}$ is said to be open if every point of S is an interior point; that is, S is open if for every $x ∈ S$ there exists an $r > 0$ such that $Br(x) ⊆ S$.

And so it has to have the following outline:
1. Let $(x, y) \in $ set $S$. Construct an open ball $B$ around $(x, y)$ such that its radius is $\epsilon$. Let $z$ be any point in $B$. Prove that $z \in S$.

Comment: Could you have stated the restriction *before*? This changes a lot of things.

Comment: @ClementC. I am sorry I forgot to state the restriction

Answer (score 2):

*Original answer, before the complete edit of the question enforcing a restriction on the type of proof.*

**Outline:**
Consider the continuous* functions $f,g\colon\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ defined respectively by
$$
f(x,y) = y-x^2
$$
and
$$
g(x,y)=x^2+y^2-1.
$$
Since $(0,\infty)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is an open set, what can you say about $f^{-1}((0,\infty))$ and $g^{-1}((0,\infty))$? And how does that give the conclusion?**

${}^*$ Prove they are indeed continuous.

${}^{**}$ That is, how *are* those sets related to what you want?